# running scrapy for X hours in script?

Tags: scrapy

Is there any way to run scrapy as part of a bash script, and only run it for a certain amount of time?
Perhaps by simulating a Ctrl-C + Ctrl-C after X hours?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the GNU [timeout](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html#timeout-invocation) command.

For example, to stop the crawler after 1 hour:

```
timeout 3600 scrapy crawl spider_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy provides [CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#closespider-timeout) option to stop crawling after a specified time period.

It is not a hard limit though - Scrapy will still process all requests it is already downloading, but it won't fetch new requests from a scheduler; in other words, CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT emulates Ctrl-C, not Ctrl-C + Ctrl-C, and tries to stop spider gracefuly. It is usually not a bad idea because killing spider may e.g. leave exported data file broken.

How much extra time will spider be alive depends on a website and on retry & concurrency settings. Default DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT is 180s; request can be retried upto 2 times, meaning each request may take ~10 min to finish in a worst case. CONCURRENT_REQUESTS is 16 by default, so there is up to 16 requests in the downloader, but they may be downloaded in parallel depending on what you're crawling. Autothrottle or CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN options may limit a number of requests executed in parallel for a single domain.

So in an absolutely worst case (sequential downloading, all requests are unresponsive and retried 2 times) spider may hang for ~3 hours with default settings. But usually in practice this time is much shorter, a few minutes. So you can set CLOSESPIDER_TIMEOUT to a value e.g. 20 minutes less than your X hours, and then use additional supervisor (like GNU timeout suggested by @lufte) to implement a hard timeout and kill a spider if its shutdown time is super-long.